# Duda con indexación de lista

Tags: python-3.x

```
nums = [1,12,24,31,51,70,100]

def contar(numeros):
    contador = 0

       while numeros[contador] <20:
        contador += 1
    return contador
```

Muy buenas, tengo el siguiente código, lo que no entiendo es la línea `numeros[contador]`.

¿Porqué se necesita indexar a contador y cual es su función?

Comment: El código recorre la lista `numeros` buscando el primer elemento mayor o igual a 20. La variable `contador` lleva el índice del elemento que estas examinando; sirve para recuperar ese valor en particular de la lista.

Comment: Cabe mencionar que si ningún número de la lista fuese menor o igual a 20, llegaría un momento en que `contador` excedría el tamaño de la lista causando una excepción. Considero esto un bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tienes una lista:

```
nums = [ 1, 12, 24, 31, 51, 70, 100 ]
```

Puedes acceder a sus elementos mediante indexación. Es como le decimos al lenguaje de programación que queremos obtener un elemento de nuestra lista en una posición específica:

```
num1 = nums[0] # Esto es 1
num2 = nums[1] # Esto es 12
num3 = nums[2] # Esto es 24
Etc.
```

Cuando emplees la indexación, debes iniciar por índice cero `[0]` en vez de índice uno `[1]`. Parece confuso, pero no lo es, ya que acá `[0]` es la primera posición, `[1]` es la segunda, `[2]` es la tercera y así sucesivamente.

---

Entendido lo anterior, podemos descomponer tu código de esta forma:

**Paso 1:**

Declara la variable `contador` con un valor `0` para iniciar en el primer elemento de la lista.

```
contador = 0
```

**Paso 2:**

Accede al numero en la posición del valor de `contador`.

```
while numeros[contador] < 20:
```

Donde

```
contador = 0 equivale a numeros[0] y devuelve 1.
contador = 1 equivale a numeros[1] y devuelve 12.
contador = 2 equivale a numeros[2] y devuelve 24.
Etc.
```

Y mientras el numero en la posición de `contador` sea menor que `20` ejecuta el paso 3.

**Paso 3:**

Suma 1 a contador por cada iteración del bucle.

```
contador += 1
```

Y, como no hay más código dentro de `while`, entonces se vuelve a evaluar de esta forma:

```
numeros[0] = 1,  1  es menor que 20, continúa
numeros[1] = 12, 12 es menor que 20, continúa
numeros[2] = 24, 24 es mayor que 20, termina
Etc.
```

Estos son `numeros[0] = 1` y `numeros[1] = 12`. Los demás no cumplen esta condición porque inician a partir de `24` que es mayor que `20`.

**Paso 4:**

Devuelve el valor que haya acumulado `contador` y finaliza la función `contar(numeros)`.

```
return contador
```

---

Adicionalmente, me preguntaste:

> Al cambiar en el código `< 20` por `> 20`, el código arroja `0` a pesar de que existen varios números mayores que `20` en la lista. ¿Porqué sucede esto?

Te explico de forma simple:

Un bucle `while` lo primero que hace es comprobar su condición antes de si quiera iniciar, si dicha condición resulta verdadera, el bucle da inicio y seguirá mientras esta condición sea verdadera, en cambio, si la condición es falsa al inicio del bucle, entonces este se detiene si tan siquiera iniciar.

Si evalúas:

```
while numeros[contador] > 20:
```

Sucede esto:

```
numeros[0] = 1,  1 es menor que 20, termina
```

Porque la condición dice que debe ser mayor que `20`, no menor. Como el bucle ni siquiera inicia, entonces tampoco suma nada a valor de `contador`, que se mantiene a su valor inicial `0`, es decir, `numeros[0]` que es `1`, `1` siempre es menor que `20` y el bucle nunca inicia, dando paso al `return contador` que devuelve el valor de `contador` que como no fue cambiado por el `while` que nunca inició, entonces es `0`.

Tu segunda pregunta fue:

> Vista mi pregunta anterior, cambié mi lista para que inicie con valores mayores que 20, pero ahora obtengo este error: IndexError: list index out of range. ¿Porqué?

Bien, basándome en tu lista, implementé y probé la siguiente:

```
numeros = [ 30, 45, 52, 31, 51, 70, 100 ]
```

Con este bloque de código:

```
numeros = [ 30, 45, 52, 31, 51, 70, 100 ]

def contar(numeros):
    contador = 0
    
    while numeros[contador] > 20:
        contador += 1
    return contador
        
print(contar(numeros))
```

Y efectivamente, obtuve `IndexError: list index out of range`. Esto es porque si te fijas, todos los valores de mi lista son mayores que `20` y, esto provoca que el `while` sea infinito, porque no encuentra un número menor que `20` que rompa la condición de: **hazlo mientras numero sea mayor que 20** y esos son todos.

A este paso, `contador` se incrementa de forma descontrolada hasta sobrepasar la cantidad de elementos de mi lista, que efectivamente provoca un error de índice fuera de rango.

Si mi lista tiene dos elementos: `[ 31, 52 ]` entonces solo puedo indexar `[0]` y `[1]`, si intento indexar cualquier otro valor, obtengo el error.

¿Solución?

Coloca un valor que rompa la condición y detenga el `while`, por ejemplo un `19` al final:

```
numeros = [ 30, 45, 52, 31, 51, 70, 19 ]
    
def contar(numeros):
    contador = 0
    
    while numeros[contador] > 20:
        contador += 1
    return contador
        
print(contar(numeros))
```

Este bloque se ejecuta correctamente e imprime `6`.

Comment: Agradezco mucho la explicación dan detallada y visual, creo que me ha ayudado a comprender algunas cosas, sin embargo al cambiar en el código '>20' en lugar de 'menor que 20' el código arroja el resultado 0 a pesar de haber varios números mayores a 20, por lo cual hay algo que no termino de comprender

Comment: Y por otro lado si cambio los valores para que inice la lista con un número mayor a 20, me da error 'list Index out of range'

Comment: @David, entiendo, cuando llegue del trabajo editaré mi respuesta para agregarte una explicación adicional a esto que preguntas.

Comment: Mientras, si mi respuesta te fue de utilidad, no olvides marcarla como aceptada empleando el check debajo del contador de votos.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente, le he dado al check, un saludo maestro

Comment: @David Me disculpo por la tardanza, me retrasé por motivos ajenos a mí. Como prometí, he agregado la respuesta a tus preguntas adicionales en mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias maestro, una explicación clara y concisa, un saludo.